# Controlling where user is sent if clicking old or expired email activation link

Tags: emails, redirect, activation

When a user visits on an old or expired email activation link, how do we control which page is loaded? In my case it's rendering a template named error.twig, but I'm not sure how that's set or where to change it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the config setting [activateAccountFailurePath](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#users) is what you are looking for.